# Why can my Docker host access containers on ipvlan when network parent is WiFi, but not when network parent is Ethernet?

Tags: networking, docker, docker-compose

I have a Docker compose setup that consists of two containers (though I will be adding more once I get past my current problem). I am running it on a Linux Mint machine with Docker `24.0.7` and Docker Compose `2.21.0`.

Network communication requirements are:

1. Containers can talk to each other
2. Containers can talk to other devices on my home subnet. This is because I have another hardware device on my home subnet that is used by one of the containers
3. The host can talk to containers. This is because one of the containers exposes a setup interface over HTTP

Depending on whether I use and wired or wireless connection, and whether I use `macvlan` or `ipvlan` networks, I get different behaviors as follows:

| Connection Type | Network Type | Inter-container comms | Container-to-subnet comms | Host-to-container comms |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Wired | `macvlan` | Works | Works | Fails |
| Wired | `ipvlan` | Works | Works | Fails |
| Wireless | `macvlan` | Works | Fails | Fails |
| Wireless | `ipvlan` | Works | Works | Works |

Although I found a combination that works (Wireless with `ipvlan`), I want to use a wired connection for practical reasons.

I'm not really a networking person and am struggling to understand the difference in behavior I'm observing. I am particularly confused as to why `ipvlan` works as expected with wireless but not wired. Can anyone tell me why this might be and how I can satisfy my requirements with a wired connection?

Here is the relevant portion of my `compose.yaml` showing how my network is defined:

```yaml
  my-network:
    driver: ${NETWORK_DRIVER:?specify the type of network driver to use}
    driver_opts:
      parent: ${NETWORK_PARENT:?specify the name of the physical network upon which the Docker stack's network will be based}
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 192.168.10.0/24
          gateway: 192.168.10.1
```

For the avoidance of doubt: I pass in the correct network parent depending on whether the driver is `macvlan` or `ipvlan` and have confirmed it post-creation of the Docker stack.

UPDATE: it gets weirder. It turns out that in order for the ipvlan network to work over WiFi, I must have an active Ethernet connection as well. As soon as I disable my Ethernet, my host can no longer access the containers. Moreover, it doesn't matter whether WiFi is enabled or not, the ipvlan will not work with Ethernet as the parent.

Comment: A MacVLAN isn’t supposed to communicate with the host. So the only question which will require more information is the reason only the WiFi adapter works with your ipvlan

Comment: How exactly did you set it up? Because both *ipvlan* and *macvlan* interfaces are bound to a specific parent interface. They also both have various options that are relevant for you like internal bridging.

Comment: @DanielB I have added a paragraph explaining my compose setup.

Comment: @Ramhound I believe that was not a deliberate "not supposed to" limitation but rather a temporary one that they removed a few releases later (with 'mode bridge')...

Comment: @u1686_grawity - The documentation I found suggests macVlan shouldn’t be possible to contact the host.

Comment: @Ramhound To be clear, I'm talking about host to container communication, not container to host. Specifically, trying to access the HTTP interface exposed by one of the containers from the host machine.

Comment: Communication *is* two-way. The "direction" only matters in context like stateful firewall filtering, in which case which side *initiated* the communication matters.